# Is there a perfmon replacement?

Tags: performance-monitoring, wmi, perfmon

I need faster stats polling and more granular display than once a second... Is there a way to configure perfmon to poll/display on faster intervals? Or is there an alternative that can query the same stats at higher frequencies?

Answer (score 2):

You can talk to WMI using PowerShell, COM, .NET and retrieve the values as often as you like.

However, be aware that simply retrieving the values more often may not make your data more granular - the update frequency of the counters may vary depending on the provider of the counter data, so you could end up retrieving the same values over and over because the counter hasn't been updated since you last retrieved it.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that given enough monitoring load you will begin to influence actual system load and skew all data accordingly.